# Create Date object in UTC in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating date object as new Date.

But it is creating date object in my time zone but when i send it through post request it get automatically converted to UTC format and some data get lost.

I want to create date object in UTC format only when i send request same date should go to server..

Is there any javascript function to create utc date object

```
var date =new Date()
```

I am using like this now and my object value is

```
Sun Apr 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

when i send data to server it is getting sent as

```
2018-03-31T18:30:00.000Z
```

Is there any way so  can create only UTC objects and there wont be any data loss because of coversion.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but I dont think this is about creating the right object differently, but serializing the object in the right way? considered [toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The only data lost is the fact that the date was created in the IST time zone … which wouldn't be data that would be there is the first place if you created a UTC object from the outset. `2018-03-31T18:30:00.000Z` **is** a UTC date string.

Answer (score 1):

The [`toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) method converts a date to a string, using the UTC time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by adding the timezone offset to the time you get from the `new Date()`

```
d = new Date();
localTime = d.getTime();
localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
utc = localTime + localOffset;
```

Describe in details here https://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/

Other option will be to use the moment.js library to get the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method. Pass your date object and it will return the date as per your requirement.

```
   function meetingDate(ExpiryDate){
   var objDate, 
   mSeconds,
   day,     
   month,
   year;
   day = ExpiryDate.substring(0, 2) - 0; 
   month = ExpiryDate.substring(3, 5) - 1; 
   year = ExpiryDate.substring(6, 10) - 0;
   mSeconds = (new Date(year, month, day)).getTime(); 
    objDate = new Date(); 
    objDate.setTime(mSeconds);
    return objDate;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = date.getUTCFullYear();
var m = date.getUTCMonth();
var d = date.getUTCDate();
var h = date.getUTCHours();
var M = date.getUTCMinutes();
var s = date.getUTCSeconds();

var utc = Date.UTC(y,m,d,h,M,s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save data in UTC on the serwer and format this date in client application by current user location.

Why? In case you save a date in the database including the time zone, for example `Sun Apr 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` it will be problematic to convert this date into a different time zone.

In the front you can use moment.js for conversion:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST

jun.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST
dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST

jun.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 10pm EST
dec.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 11pm EST
```

More examples for moment.js you can find [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)